# Debug mode shows records while the NUnit runner throws IndexOutofRange Exception

Tags: c#

I can find a row if I run in debug mode, however dont see the select query returns a record in NUnit test run

```
public static DataTable GetAddressStatusOfDevice(string deviceId, string connectionString)
        {
            string commandText = "SELECT AddressStatus FROM dbo.DeviceAddresses WHERE DeviceID = @ID;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {                
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
                command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
                command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = deviceId;
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt; 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. In the refered "duplicate" question, the user is responsible getting a non-existing row (by using `ds.Tables["QA"].Rows[recno]`). In this case, the user is NOT referening to any row with any index. If this exception is correct it occurs somewhere in system code.

Comment: I agree with Martin. This is really a different question about debug mode shows records and NUnit test runner shows no records in this sql connection. There is something related to the timing I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Would that make a difference if you write it like:

```
public static DataTable GetAddressStatusOfDevice(string deviceId, string connectionString)
{
    string commandText = "SELECT AddressStatus FROM dbo.DeviceAddresses WHERE DeviceID = @ID;";
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(commandText, connectionString);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = deviceId;
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

(Don't know a way to ask this in comments)

Comment: It doesnt help Cetin. Thanks